# python pd.read_excel [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling, try-except

I am struggling with the following issue:

I receive a daily .xls file. However, the format of that file is not the same as the extension. Sometimes it's .xlsx and sometimes it's .xlsb. I am trying to read the contents of this file into a pandas data frame, so I wrote the following code:

```
import openpyxl
import pyxlsb 
import pyodbc
import os
import pandas as pd

try:
    full_name1 = "my_file.xls"
    full_name2 = "my_file.xlsx"
    os.rename(full_name1, full_name2)
    df = pd.read_excel(full_name2, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2', engine = 'openpyxl', skiprows = range(0, 7), usecols = "A:X")

except:
    
    full_name1 = "my_file.xlsx"
    full_name2 = "my_file.xlsb"
    os.rename(full_name1, full_name2)
    df = pd.read_excel(full_name2, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2', engine = 'pyxlsb', skiprows = range(0, 7), usecols = "A:X")
```

However, I get the error:

[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'my_file.xlsx' -> 'my_file.xlsb'

And the 'my_file.xlsx' seems to still be in use.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you really need to rename the file? Why not just using ``pd.read_excel`` with different engine? If the first one does not work, then use the second one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to rename. Because the format of the excel file (51 - which is the format for .xlsx or 50 - for.xlsb) and the extension (.xls) are not consistent, python throws an error for both xlrd and openpyxl/pyxlsb.

Answer (score 0):

Why not going through the list of files in the directory?:

```
import os
for directory, subdirlist, filelist in os.walk('C:\\Google Drive\\Python\\Uhlmann\\'):
    for file in filelist:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2', engine = 'openpyxl', skiprows = range(0, 7), usecols = "A:X")
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution - it adds a bit to run-time of the program, but it works:

```
import openpyxl
import pyxlsb 
import pyodbc
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

full_name1 = "my_file.xls"
full_name2 = "my_file.xlsx"
full_name3 = "my_file.xlsb"

shutil.copy(full_name1, full_name3)
os.rename(full_name1, full_name2)

try:
    df = pd.read_excel(full_name2, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2', engine = 'openpyxl', skiprows = range(0, 7), usecols = "A:X")

except:
    df = pd.read_excel(full_name3, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2', engine = 'pyxlsb', skiprows = range(0, 7), usecols = "A:X")
```